# My web extension can't execute scripts in opened webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm trying to make a web extension for Firefox that will open a .webm file in a new tab, and force it to auto-loop. But the part of my script that's on the new page doesn't execute. It doesn't throw an error or anything, it just doesn't execute. I've been debugging it using Firefox's built-in debugging console (ctrl+shift+alt+i).

It works fine if I open the webpage in firefox directly (as in, by using alt+o instead of using the web extension to load it).

I also can't use window.open(), so I had to use chrome.tabs.create(). I don't know if that's related.

Here's my code...

manifest.js

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "LoopWebm",
"version": "1.0",

"description": "Adds a context menu option to videos that allows you to open them in a new tab or window (based on User Preferences), where it will play and auto-loop. Intended for use with .webm videos.",

"icons": {
    "16": "icons/loop16.png",
    "32": "icons/loop32.png",
    "48": "icons/loop48.png"
},


"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},


"permissions": [
"contextMenus",
"tabs",
"activeTab",
"<all_urls>"
]


}
```

And background.js

```
function onCreated(n) {
if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log("error creating item:" + chrome.runtime.lastError);
} else {
    console.log("item created successfully");
}
}

function onRemoved() {
if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log("error removing item:" + chrome.runtime.lastError);
} else {
    console.log("item removed successfully");
}
}

//add my extension to the .webm (and other videos) context menu
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "ShorkLoop",
    title: "ShorkLooper",
    contexts: ["video"]
}, onCreated);

//add a listener to this extension's context menu
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    console.log("got to the background listener!");
    var newIndex = tab.id;  //tab.id is 1-based, tabs.create is 0-based. Thus this puts newIndex in the next spot
    //window.open() doesn't work here. Doesn't even throw an error in the debugger or stop the function.
    chrome.tabs.create({ "url": chrome.extension.getURL("myPage.html?insrc=" + info.srcUrl), "index":newIndex});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(newIndex, {code:'document.getElementById("Video1").src = "http://video.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm";'});
    console.log("got to the end of the background listener!");
});
```

and myPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function videoSwitch()
    {
        console.log("Switching video!");
        //switches the video's source
        //works fine if I load it on its own
        //but doesn't work when used in a webextension 
        document.getElementById("Video1").src = "http://video.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="videoSwitch()" bgcolor=#222222>
    <video id="Video1" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" controls autoplay loop src='http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm'>
    </video>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: Following Duskwuff's link, I got it to work by making a new .js file. I put the  tag in the HTML's head, moved videoSwitch() to the new .js file, and also added

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
videoSwitch();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the chrome's plugin,not useful for Firefox.If you want to run in Firefox,you have to learn how to develop Firefox's plugin

Comment: Firefox has adopted [the WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), which is largely compatible with (and looks almost identical to) the Chrome extension API.

Comment: I searched the information online,It seems says the Firefox's WebExtensions API will be used on December

Answer (score 0):

First: You can't use `window.open` because your extension's script doesn't run in the context of the current page. It runs in a separate background page which is never visible, and which doesn't have access to some Javascript APIs that require a "real" window to work.

Anyways, your call to `chrome.tabs.executeScript` isn't doing anything because it runs *immediately* after the tab is created, before the page has actually loaded. Since the page hasn't loaded yet, `document.getElementById("Video1")` doesn't return anything.

The inline script is failing for a different reason. Pages that are part of an extension are subject to [a strict security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) which does not permit inline scripts. You will need to move this script into a separate Javascript file and load it in your HTML file using a `<script src=…></script>` tag.

Comment: Informative answer! ...But it didn't work.
Same problem: It works fine if I load the webpage on its own, but when I load it through the web extension it opens the big rabbit video, instead of replacing it with the other one like it's supposed to.

Comment: I changed the .html document's body to...

-`<video id="Video1" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" controls autoplay loop src='http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm'></video>

<script src="videoLoader.js"></script>`